# Anglesharp Elements Extension missing

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I have updated to the latest version on Anglesharp Nuget library v.0.9.9. I can see on the Github page https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/commit/7af0ef9c3cfd3d96803fa6ccff326f186744c99c that Anglesharp has extensions added for element related methods. But I am unable to access those with my referenced Anglesharp DLL.

Any idea how these can be enabled or accessed?

Comment: Any specific method that you can't see..??

Comment: @too_cool I am trying to access the method public static Boolean IsEnabled(this IElement element)

Comment: Also if i try using this command 
`AngleSharp.Extensions.ElementExtensions.IsEnabled(element);`
I get the error message saying ".. is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Answer (score 1):

You can't access that method as it is not public the class `ElementExtensions` has  Default Access Modifiers that means `Internal` which is assembly scope so that is only accessible from code in the same .exe or .dll

Comment: Ok @too_cool . Is there a way within Anglesharp that I access the isEnabled property of the DOM elements? I can see the method being there but unable to access it due to its protection.

Comment: @KimSmith Not sure if its possible but still you can give a try with `Reflection` .. bcz somewhere I have read "You can call anything with reflection"..:)